# Nav bien distribuido con CSS

Tags: css, grid, display

este es mi primer mensaje, así que siento si cometo algún error al presentarla.

Estoy intentando crear una barra superior en el Header, con el icono a la izquierda, parte del menú en el centro, y dos botones a la izquierda, pero no consigo hacerlo.

Os envío capturas de lo que tengo hecho y el enlace de mi código. Gracias por toda ayuda que me podáis dar.

https://github.com/Kakita5595/p-games.git

[image: Imagen con el Grid activado]

Comment: ¡El código debe ir _en la pregunta_! Si el enlace externo cae, se perderá la parte esencial de la pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Como tu caso es en css, puedes insertar un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) para adjuntar un [repro].

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de conseguir lo que necesitas es añadirle `flex` al contendor padre de los elementos, que en tu caso sería el *header*.
Para ello añádele una clase al *header*, por ejemplo `class=“contenedor”` y los otros elementos añádelos en 3 div diferentes: el logo en uno, el texto en otro y los botones en otro.
Después añádele los siguientes estilos a la `class=“contendor”`

`.contenedor{ display: flex; justify-content: space-around; }`

Con ello conseguirás que se distribuyan los 3 elementos en el header de manera ordenada.